# Solr splits a field containing a URL when copying from destination to a copyfield

Tags: json, xml, indexing, solr

I'm using Solr 4.5.1 and i have these two fields indexed in solr :

**schema.xml**

```
<field name="event_id" type="custom_string"  indexed="true"  stored="true" />
<field name="text" type="text_fr" indexed="true"  multiValued="true" stored="true"/>
<copyField source="event_id" dest="text"/>
<fieldType name="text_fr" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
        <analyzer>
            <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
            <!-- normalisation des accents, cédilles, e dans l'o,...-->
            <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
            <!-- suppression des doublons éventuels -->
            <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

**solrconfig.xml**

```
<requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">
    <!-- default values for query parameters can be specified, these
     will be overridden by parameters in the request
  -->
    <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
        <int name="rows">10</int>
        <str name="df">text</str>
        <!--Custom default for Iris -->
        <str name="fl">id</str>
        <str name="hl">on</str>
        <str name="hl.simple.pre">[###</str>
        <str name="hl.simple.post">###]</str>
        <str name="hl.fl">event_id</str>
    </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

As you have noticed in solrconfig.xml i'm highlighting the field event_id on the /select requesthandler, PS the field event_id always contains a href.

When i store for instance this url on the event_id field "htp://XXX.ZZZ.WWW/OFF" and i try to query it using this query :

```
event_id:(htp\:\/\/XXX.ZZZ.WWW\/OFF)
```

i get this result which is correct :

```
{
"responseHeader": {
"status": 0,
"QTime": 11,
"params": {
  "indent": "true",
  "q": "event_id:(htp\\:\\/\\/XXX.ZZZ.WWW\\/OFF)",
  "_": "1432653054406",
  "wt": "json"
}
},
"response": {
"numFound": 2,
"start": 0,
"docs": [
  {
    "id": "ccb7f2bf-c758-4ebe-bcbe-48f73f43274d"
  },
  {
    "id": "4f9386c9-a1fb-4918-b163-86ff20cb792f"
  }
]
},
"highlighting": {
"ccb7f2bf-c758-4ebe-bcbe-48f73f43274d": {
  "event_id": [
    "[###htp://XXX.ZZZ.WWW/OFF###]"
  ]
},
"4f9386c9-a1fb-4918-b163-86ff20cb792f": {
  "event_id": [
    "[###htp://XXX.ZZZ.WWW/OFF###]"
  ]
}
} 
}
```

but when i try this query:

```
text:(htp\:\/\/XXX.ZZZ.WWW\/OFF)
```

i get this result:

```
{
"responseHeader": {
"status": 0,
"QTime": 9,
"params": {
  "indent": "true",
  "q": "text:(htp\\:\\/\\/XXX.ZZZ.WWW\\/OFF)",
  "_": "1432653585146",
  "wt": "json"
 }
},
"response": {
"numFound": 2,
"start": 0,
"docs": [
  {
    "id": "ccb7f2bf-c758-4ebe-bcbe-48f73f43274d"
  },
  {
    "id": "4f9386c9-a1fb-4918-b163-86ff20cb792f"
  }
]
},
 "highlighting": {
 "ccb7f2bf-c758-4ebe-bcbe-48f73f43274d": {},
 "4f9386c9-a1fb-4918-b163-86ff20cb792f": {}
}
}
```

and as shown in the output the event_id isn't highlighted, as far as I'm concerned, I think that when the event_id is indexed on Solr it's indexed as a string, while when it's being copied to the text it's spited to tokens "htp","XXX.ZZZ.WWW" and "OFF" due to the presence of the tokenizer, I think that this might be the source of my problem since it works when i index a simple string(example event_id="OFF") instead of a url("http://..."), can you help me understand why please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic requirement while copying is that, the types should be compatible. Your event_id is custom_string type, which I am assuming it as normal string. However text is of type text_fr, which has tokenizers and [filters](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory). You can try both fields to be custom_string, unless otherwise, you have specific requirement to use tokenizers

Comment: Yeah actually i need tokenizers and filters in text.

Comment: So you can target event_id, to have a different type. In short, you are getting everything right as per Solr usage. May be the design needs to be revisited to have a proper usage, like changing the types and identifying their scope, so that it wont affect other existing implementations. If you need more information, you can share your requirement. Happy coding :)